# Stripe Firefox Chrome Extension redirect url not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments

Seems like this question has been asked plenty of times, but every time has slightly a different answer that isn't applicable. I am taking a chrome extension and trying to port it to Firefox. It is a react-app that uses an HTML page to load my App.js.

my manifest.json:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": ["images/*"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/; script-src-elem https://js.stripe.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

my HTML file:

```
...
  <div id="root"> </div>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script src="App.js"></script>
</body>
```

my App.js file:

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

 if (sessionId) {
        // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
        // Init Stripe
        const stripe = loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
```

It fails because it keeps saying the following error:
[image: Screenshot of error message]

I cannot figure out what the issue is and would love some help!

Comment: `script-src-elem` doesn't appear to be a valid CSP directive for Chrome extensions. Try using `script-src` instead for stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Comment: same issue...`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://js.stripe.com/v3/ (“script-src”).`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed when I removed apis.google.com -- in case anyone needs this in the future, then stripe started to work.